# PATH to mysql is saved in .zshrc but does not show on echo $PATH. mysql --version gets "Command not found" error

Tags: mysql, terminal, path, zsh, zshrc

I downloaded and installed mysql via their package installer. It installed successfully and I can verify that the server is running.
[mysql server status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OyaG.png)
When I enter mysql --version I get the zsh: command not found: mysql error.
[terminal and .zshrc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pARvT.png)
I added the path /usr/local/mysql/bin(I verified the location) in .zshrc and restarted the terminal, it doesn't show on the echo and the terminal still says "command not found"

I've also added it on a separate line via - echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc , and still get the error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure **that** modified .zshrc has been consumed by your current shell? Open a child shell by doing a `zsh -x` and verify the setting of your PATH.